# If $F_m$ is the set of germs which vanish at the mainfold poin $m$, what is meant by $F_{m}/F_{m}{}^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

In [Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387908946#otherversion=9781475717990), by , Frank W. Warner we are given the following definitions:

[image]

Then, in Lemma 1.16 we are told: *$M_m$ is naturally isomorphic with $(F_{m}/F_{m}{}^2)^{\ast}$.* The symbol ${}^\ast$ denotes dual vector space.)

$M_m$ is the tangent space of to the manifold $M$ at the point $m$.

To begin with, I'm not sure what it means for $f$ and $g$ to "agree on some neighborhood". Dose that mean "in the limit as the radius of the neighborhood goes to zero", or does it mean they are exactly identical, as in the implicit function theorem?

I have some vague idea of what an ideal is.  For rings, an ideal is a non-empty subset $\mathfrak{a}$ of a ring $\mathfrak{R}$ such that for $a,b\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $r\in\mathfrak{R}$, we have $a-b\in\mathfrak{a}$ and $ra\in\mathfrak{a}$.

But main question is: what does $F_{m}/F_{m}{}^2$ mean?

Comment: “$f$ and $g$ agree on some neighborhood of $x$” means that there is an open subset $x \in U \subset M$ such that $f_{|U}=g_{|U}$. For your second question: $F_m,F_m^2$ are $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, and $F_m^2$ is a subspace of $F_m$. So $F_m/F_m^2$ is the quotient of $F_m$ by $F_m^2$, ie the set of all the $x+F_m^2$, $x\in F_m$, with the natural operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea of this definition is that you want to capture local variations of functions that give you the vectors. In some coordinate system where the point $m$ is 0  a generic function vanishing at $m=0$ looks like
$$
f(x)=a_\mu x^\mu +b_{\mu\nu}x^\mu x^\nu+\dots 
$$
We mod out by $F_m^2$ precisely to remove higher order terms as $b_{\mu\nu}x^\mu x^\nu+\dots \in F_m^2$  we have
$$
f(x)=a_\mu x^\mu \,\,\text{mod} \, F_m^2  
$$
and we see the natural identification of the dual of $F_m/F_m^2$ with the tangent space. Note this also explains why we took only the functions vanishing at 0.

The precise definition of the quotient of a ring $R$ by an ideal $I$ is: an element $[r]\in R/I$ is the equivalence class of $r$ under the equivalence relation generated by $r\sim r+i$ for any $i\in I$. The properties of an ideal you mentioned above are precisely what you need for $R/I$ to also have a ring structure.

Comment: For medical reasons, I'm fading fast, and won't be able to give this much coherent attention for a couple days, but I do want to ask if that should be $f(x)\text{mod} \,\, F_m^2=a_\mu x^\mu$ instead?  I'm just thinking in terms of, for example, integers where $a/b+a\% b=a$.

Comment: a ok. the usual notation, is $a=b \,\text{mod} (I)$ means the equivalence class of $a$ is the same as the equivalence class $b$. For integers for instance, you usually write $5=2\, \text{mod} (3)$. The $\mod I$ is to be understood as saying that the equation is valid in $R/I$, not as doing some kind of operation in $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to accept that I will have to return to this in the future.  I believe the gist of what is happening is that  $F_m$ is the set of all functions of the form of your $f\left(x\right)$, and $F_m^2$ is the set of all $f\left(x\right)$ which do not have first order terms.  $F_m/F_m^2$ is the complement of $F_m^2$ in $F_m$, which consists of only first order terms.  My expectation is that, replacing $x$ with $dx$ so that we have $f\left(x\right)=a_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ will produce the vector field dual to $M_m$.  So the ${}^{\ast}$ is a bit redundant.